# Proving cylinder is a Manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

I need to prove that a cylinder in $R^3$ is a Manifold by using the definition.

So basically I have to show that It is locally diffeomorphic to an open subset of $R^2$.

Can anyone help me with that. I am new to the subject.

Thanks & regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

Use the fact that a circle is a one dimensional manifold based on the mapping $t \mapsto (\cos t, \sin t)$ and that $(u,v) \mapsto (\cos u, \sin u, v)$ is  a parameterization of a cylinder.

Comment: I think I get it, we can actually cover every point with that parametrization only right??

Comment: Yes, that's right. Just take care that the mapping is not one-to-one. So you need to reduce the domain to obtain charts.

Comment: How about one period of trigonometric functions?

Comment: Yes you almost got it. You can't take a full period as the mapping is still not one-to-one. But you can use two charts based for example on the intervals $(-\pi,\pi)$ and $(0,2\pi)$. The transition maps are equal to the identity.

Comment: But how is the mapping not 1-1 in say (0,2π). Circle will be covered only once right? @mathcounterexamples.net

Comment: In the open interval $(0,2\pi)$ the mapping is one-to-one. We however miss one point of the circle. This is why at least two charts are required to represent the full manifold.